Folder robocopied from a portable USB drive to a laptop PC hard disk unaccountably becomes system+hidden
I just copied many files from a portable disk to a new laptop PC using robocopy /MIR in a cmd window, under Windows 11.
It all seemed to go well; I can open files and folders under C:\X\, e.g. in C:\X\A\, C:\X\B\, etc., which I take as proof that 'something' has been copied and the folder exists.
However, folder 'X' is not displayed in File Explorer, nor is it listed by dir C:\.
Path This PC \ Acer(C:) \ X appears on top of the File Explorer window, and I see all folders under 'X', but then when I navigate a level up, and path This PC \ Acer(C:) is displayed on top, 'X' is not listed...
How can this be explained?
As per previous post title, I thought that the folder was not hidden; I did not do anything to make it hidden, and when I selected the option to show hidden objects, some semi-transparent folders appeared in C:, but not that one.
I ran the standard file system check and it found no errors.

EDIT: more info after further work
I saw this post although it seems to refer to thumb drives, whereas my issue is happening on a hard disk of a PC.
If I do dir /A \ as suggested, 'X' is found (!).
dir /A:H shows folder "C:\X" (as if it were hidden ?)... but then it still does not show it in Windows Explorer even when I select the option to show hidden elements... so is it hidden or not, or what is it? First time in my life I've seen something like this...
attrib C:\X returns SH. So a folder that I just robocopied from a disk to another has somehow become a system, hidden one??? What sort of black magic is this?
All other folders I copied during the same session have attrib 'A'.
I might do something like attrib -S -H C:\X, but I am not comfortable messing with this stuff, so I'd like to hear some expert advice first. Especially because I have no idea how this happened in the first place.
Any idea what may have caused such a thing? And is it safe to do attrib -S -H C:\X followed perhaps by attrib +A C:\X?

The only way this would occur is either due to the attributes of the source folder, which are copied with /mir (most likely reason - verify by listing the directory's attributes on the USB or access the GUI folder Properties), or the root of C:'s attributes have been manually modified to assign system,hidden attributes to anything copied into it (least likely, especially with /mir since the default is to copy DAT for files and directories)

@JW0914 : indeed, re the hidden folders, bcs as I mentioned, I copied other folders from the USB drive to C:, and those had attribute 'A' in C:. Going to check the attribute of the 'X' folder in the USB drive now.

The folder had attribute 'A' in the USB drive. This is very mysterious. BTW in the meantime I went ahead and did the attribute reassignment. Seems OK for now.
